# Link Textbox to Query Column

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a query which has the following fields

```
OrderID
[Forms]![FMain_Orders]![OrderID]

Sum Of the Board Feet

Sum of the Board Price
```

What I am trying to do is populate a text box using the information in the above query specifically the Sum of the Board Feet

I am new to coding in VBA so researching I was unsure that I should be looking for. Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you would be better off using *DSum* in an expression for the textbox like:

```
=DSum("[NameOfYourFieldWithBoardPrice]","[YourOrderDetailsTable]","[OrderID]=" & [Forms]![FMain_Orders]![OrderID] & "")
```

or, if the textbox is on FMain Orders:

```
=DSum("[NameOfYourFieldWithBoardPrice]","[YourOrderDetailsTable]","[OrderID]=" & Me![OrderID] & "")
```